Continuity of a mapping on a space of polynomial
I consider the set
$$
\mathcal{U}=\{u_{a,b}:x\in[0,1]\mapsto ax^2+bx : a\leq 0, [b\leq a\quad\text{or}\quad b\geq -a]\} 
$$
And the set of associated coefficients
$$
\mathcal{C} =\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} : a\leq 0, [b\leq a\quad\text{or}\quad b\geq -a]\} 
$$
I would like to prove that the mapping $\phi(u_{a,b}) = (a,b)$ is continuous (I specify that it is for the topology of the uniform convergence for $\mathcal{U}$).
Let $u_{a_0,b_0}\in\mathcal{U}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Then we know that we can control the distance on $\mathcal{U}_{coeff}$ as follows
$$
\lVert u_{a,b} - u_{a_0,b_0}\rVert_{\infty}\leq\delta,\quad\delta>0\quad(1)
$$
However using this, the best thing I can see is that $\lVert a - a_0 + b-b_0\rvert \leq\delta$ (the case where $x=1$)
In the space $\mathcal{C}$ I first considered the norm $\lVert .\rVert_{1}$ but the fact that
$$
\lvert a - a_0 + b-b_0\rvert\leq\lvert a -a_0\rvert + \lvert b-b_0\rvert 
$$
make it not useful I think.
I then tried to use the maximum norm on $\mathcal{C}$ in order to prove that $(1)$ implies $\lvert a -a_0\rvert\leq\epsilon$ and $\lvert b-b_0\rvert\leq\epsilon$ but the best I have is
$$
\lvert a - a_0\rvert \leq\lvert a-a_0 + b-b_0\rvert +\lvert b_0 -b\rvert\leq\delta + \lvert b_0 -b\rvert
$$
I would like to know where I get wrong in my way to prove this please, because I think that it is very intuitive that we should have the continuity of such a mapping, and even more (I Think that is should be an homeomorphim).
Thank you a lot

$(a,b)\mapsto|u_{a,b}|_\infty$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^2$, and all norms on $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent. So, $\phi$ is a (bi-lipschitz) homeomorphism.

@AnneBauval Thank you a lot ! Indeed the $x$ acts as a « weight » here when considered as a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ something I did not notice ! $\varphi$ is even more : an isometry, no ?

Your map is the restriction of a linear isomorphism between 2d vector spaces so it is continuous. You could try to express the inverse with evaluation maps

No it is not an isometry (except of course if you equiv artificially $\Bbb R^2$ with the norm of my first comment).

@AnneBauval My framework was the one you give in parenthesis I should have specify sorry. Thank you !

General theoretical arguments were given in comments. More explicitely, a rough but sufficient bound is obtained via evaluation maps (as suggested in @julio_es_sui_glace's comment), for instance $$u_{a,b}(1)=a+b\quad\text{and}\quad u_{a,b}(1/2)=\frac a4+\frac b2.$$
$$|b|=|4u_{a,b}(1/2)-u_{a,b}(1)|\le5\|u_{a,b}\|_\infty$$
$$|a|=|2u_{a,b}(1)-4u_{a,b}(1/2)|\le6\|u_{a,b}\|_\infty$$
and $\Bbb R^2\ni(a,b)\mapsto u_{a,b}$ is linear.

Thank you for the detailed answer !
